# Why does this method give no output?

Tags: php, laravel

```
private function getWord()
{   
    $words = DB::select('select "name" from words');
    $word = $words[array_rand($words)];
    if ($this->gamedata->getUsedWords() !== null) {
        foreach ($this->gamedata->getUsedWords() as $usedWord) {
            if ($usedWord == $word) {
                return getWord();
            }
        }
    }
    $this->gamedata->addUsedWord($word);
    return $word;
}
```

This method somehow does give me an empty "$word". At least it's not a String.
In the table words I have 1 entry and the method "getUsedWords()" is just to check if I used the word before.
I just want to get 1 random word from the table, which wasn't used before.
The error I get if I want to read this output in my view: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string"

I save this value in the class "GameData".

```
    $this->gamedata->setWord($this->getWord());
```

This method lokks like this:

```
public function setWord($word)
{
    $this->word = $word;
}
```

In my view I use:

```
{{$gamedata->getWord()}}
```

to write the word on the page.

Comment: You can just do a single `LEFT JOIN` between words and used_words to get a row from the former that isn't in the latter.

Comment: `SELECT "name"` probably doesn't do what you think it does?

Comment: Where's the code that calls `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Should `return getWord()` not be `return $this->getWord();`?

Comment: I have "id", "name" and "category" in my db. I thought it would return the column "name"

Comment: `"name"`, with the quotes will literally give you the string `name`. Get rid of the quotes if you want to use the column, or use backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the select statement inside the select. A small visit to the docs would have shown you that it should be:

```
$words = DB::table('words')->select('name')->get();
```

Comment: `DB::select()` is direct statement, and is a perfectly valid use case when running raw queries. It will return the result of a read statement as an array of objects, where each object is a representation of a result row.

Comment: I changed the statement but i still get the same error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: Yes @sraLton thats because the statement returns objects. You need to get the name from the object before you print it because Laravel Blade escapes the output automatically.

Comment: So you can use something like `$word->name`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to even try to explain the many ways your code is sub-optimal, I will just suggest you rewrite it as:

```
private function getWord()
{   
    $word = \DB::table('words') 
               ->when(!empty($this->getUsedWords()), function ($query) { 
                    $query->whereNotIn('word', $this->getUsedWords());
               })->inRandomOrder()
                 ->value('word')

    $this->gamedata->addUsedWord($word);
    return $word;
}
```

On other words, from the table `words` in random order get the first element and in case the used words is not empty exclude those words.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't quite use that function in order to return a word that hasn't been used before, since each time you call the function, you are returning all of the words and then parsing through them, calling a database query each time.

I would have a table which contains the list of words and then a usage count next to each word. Since you aren't bothered by what word you use, just provided it hasn't been used before, I would construct a SELECT statement which would choose the first result, ordered by usage count ascending. That way, once you've used all of the words once, and it will happen, it will then loop through and start again.